# How to find companies' Form 10-K annual reports? Why might a company not file one?

Tags: united-states, investing, stock-markets, start-up

I am trying to find 10-K forms for some companies, but couldn't find what I was looking for. How would I find Form 10-K for any of these start-ups below? I already tried http://www.sec.gov.

```
stackexchange.com
wikimedia.com
uopeople.com
coursera.org
edx.org
udacity.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm doubtful whether the companies you listed are actually *public* companies — that is, companies whose shares already trade freely on a public stock exchange.

For instance, [Stack Overflow](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/) (the company that owns [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com), of which this site is a part of) is not yet a public company — rather, it was [raising venture funds](http://finance.yahoo.com/news/andreessen-horowitz-leads-40m-financing-142130641.html?nf=1&bypass=true) until recently.

Many companies remain *privately held*, or simply *private*. A private company has few shareholders, and the shares are not listed on a stock exchange (but may be transacted privately). Companies typically remain private until attaining a certain size. They can go public via an initial public offering (IPO) if they wish to tap the public markets to fund further expansion. Even then, not all larger companies opt to go public.

The public/private distinction is important with respect to what you seek because U.S. securities law only requires *public* companies, and those about to go public soon, to regularly disclose that kind of information. See [SEC.gov - Form 10-K](http://www.sec.gov/answers/form10k.htm).

So, I would suggest you first try to establish whether a company you are interested in is publicly traded, or soon to be publicly traded. Provided you can establish that, then finding the information reports and forms that the company must disclose (assuming the company is/will be traded on an exchange in the U.S.) should be straightforward. In fact, many of them will have an investors section on their corporate web site to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, form 10-K is only required for publicly traded companies. I am pretty sure that Wikimedia is not public. The others on your list may, also, not be public.